# Ubuntu 14.10 blank screen on fresh install, new to this

Tags: boot

Completely new to installing this, and confused as to why it is like this after I login.

http://i58.tinypic.com/smfrqw.jpg

Comment: Kindly explain how did you install. Is it a live CD or USB? Is it a dual boot? Did you partition?

Comment: I used a USB to install, no dual boot, selected the option to erase Win8.1, and I did not partition.

Comment: Try to re-install.

Comment: I did, and it's doing the same thing.